# Spinner custom drop down view weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-spinner

In a spinner I've put the following custom drop down view

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_allowance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_allowance"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_allowance"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_allowance"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_allowance"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Repas du midi" />
```

and made a custom adapter like this :

```
class SpinnerAllowanceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    SpinnerAllowanceAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return position != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_allowance);
        ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_allowance);

        if (position == 0) {
            // Set the hint text color gray
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            iv.setImageResource(getAllowanceIcon(position));
        }
        return view;
    }



    private int getAllowanceIcon(int position){
        int drawableId;

        //image selection

        return drawableId;
    }
}
```

When no item are selected it work perfectly. But when the user select an item from the spinner the image view from this item disappears in the drop down view.

[drop down view when no items have been selected by the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKSrp.png)

[Drop down view, image dispared on item selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NesID.png)

Is this a normal behaviour or a missing part in my code to always have the image view active?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `android:visibility="gone"` from imageview like this

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView_allowance"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_allowance"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_allowance"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp" />
```